# Custom List View query in contacts module

Tags: sugarcrm

I have below query to be implemented in contacts module.

```
SELECT DISTINCT bean_id FROM `email_addr_bean_rel` as a,
(select S.email_address_id from contacts R 
INNER JOIN email_addr_bean_rel S ON R.id = S.bean_id 
and S.bean_module='contacts' and S.deleted=0 
group by S.email_address_id 
having count(S.email_address_id)>1) as Dup
where Dup.email_address_id=a.email_address_id 
and a.bean_module='contacts' and a.deleted=0
```

How do i implement this with custom_from , custom_select or custom_where

Answer (score 0):

Changeing the Where clause of a query is quite easy but if you want to change the select and from that's a bigger problem.

Two ways to achive this are:

1) create a create_new_list_query() function in Contact.php (the module core class)

```
function create_new_list_query()
{       

    $return_array = Array();

    $return_array['select'] = "SELECT DISTINCT bean_id ";   
    $return_array['from'] = " FROM `email_addr_bean_rel` as a, (select  .email_address_id from contacts R INNER JOIN email_addr_bean_rel S ON R.id = S.bean_id and S.bean_module='contacts' and S.deleted=0 group by S.email_address_id having count(S.email_address_id)>1) as Dup ";                               
    $return_array['where'] = " where Dup.email_address_id=a.email_address_id and a.bean_module='contacts' and a.deleted=0 ";    
    $return_array['order_by'] = "";

    return  $return_array['select'] . $return_array['from'] . $return_array['where']. $return_array['order_by'];

}
```

You can choose the display fields by adding them to the select and the listviewdefs.php

```
$listViewDefs ['Contacts'] =
    array (
        'bean_id' => array (
            'width' => '15%',
            'label' => 'LBL_ID',
            'default' => true,
    ),
```

);

Watch out this actions will severely change you contacts module and if you want you original behavior back revert all changes afterwards

2) the better way would be to create a custom module with the same changes as 1)